# What if I override the bind function of Jtable.?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-api

Actually I'm learning component development in which I'm creating a table class which extends JTable. 
I am also overriding the __construct which is fine up to, but when I override the bind function Like Below:

```
function bind($src, $egnore=array()){
  parent::bind($src, $egnore=array())
}
```

it will show **save failed with following error** but if I remove this override, save/edit functions works fine.
Why is this happening? What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have to return the return value of the parent's bind method:

```
function bind($src, $egnore=array()){
    return parent::bind($src, $egnore=array());
}
```

JTable::bind returns true if everything went well, but your method does not return true so Joomla thinks something went wrong.

Comment: I agree with @fruppei. If you don't have any custom validations, you don't need to override the bind() function, you can remove those 3 lines.